# Reducing a system of two boolean algebra assertions to a single one

Tags: boolean-algebra

Given a system of two Boolean Algebra equalities

```
a = b.
c = d.
```

one can exhibit a single equation

```
F(a,b,c,d) = 0.
```

which is equivalent to the former system. (Symmetric difference is pivotal for constructing such quaternary operation F(a,b,c,d)).

Questions:

- Is there binary operation `x ? y` (infix notation) such that

  a ? c = b ? d.

  is equivalent to the original system?
- Is there binary operation `x ? y`  such that

  a ? b = c ? d.

  is equivalent to the original system?

*Edit (June 13):* The question is more subtle than I managed to convey. Boolean algebra is a finitely definable variety. I was wondering if we can get a single axiom system by combining identities. Padmanabhan proved in 1968 that every definable class of lattices (such as BA) can be defined by a single identity within the class of lattices. The key observation in his method is equipping the identities

```
a = b.
c = d.
```

with *disjoint* sets of variables. Then, simple disjunction

```
a v c = b v d.
```

would do.

Comment: You could write a small program to generate all possibilities to find out!

Comment: I'm looking for mathematical argument; writing a program with exhaustive check of 16 candidate functions will unlikely give me any insight. For example, generalizing the question to 3 equalities reveals the flaw in the second suggested equivalent equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no such binary operation.

This is easy to prove with a counting argument.  Given a candidate binary operation $?$, count the number $n$ of boolean values $x,y$ such that $x?y$ is true.   Out of the 16 possible values for $a,b,c,d$, exactly $m=n^2+(4-n)^2$ of them will satisfy $a?c = b?d$.  The possible values for $m$ are $m \in \{16,10,8\}$.  However, there are only 4 possible values of $a,b,c,d$ such that $a=b$ and $c=d$, which is not in the set of possible values for $m$.

Or, you could do as David Clarke suggests and write a tiny program to enumerate all possibilities.  Frankly, you probably should have done that before asking in any case; that would have helped you ask a more specific question, such as "I know no such binary operation exists; can you give me any insight why not?".